# Solving inequality with partial sum of binomial coefficient

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, systems-of-equations, approximation

Given an integer $n$ and another one $m \leq n$, I am trying to get a tight upper and lower bound for the parameter $k \leq n$ such that the following inequality involving a partial sum with binomial coefficients (let's say *"binomial partial sum"*) holds:
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} {{n}\choose{i}} \leq 2^m \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1} {{n}\choose{i}}$$

That is to say : *the largest $k$ up to which the binomial partial sum is the closest to $2^m$*

I have already found a trivial upper bound (see below), but it seems very rough... And I keep failing for the lower bound.

**My question :** Is it possible to get a tighter upper bound and a tight lower bound ?

**Trivial upper bound**

To get a trivial upper bound for $k$ :

- we consider the known upper bound $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{p} {{n}\choose{i}} \leq (n+1)^{p}$ for the binomial partial sum
- we rewrite the equation by using this bound in order to get what we want :

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} {{n}\choose{i}} \leq (n+1)^{k} \leq 2^m$$

- Which leads to the following upper bound :

$$k \leq \frac{m}{\log(n+1)}$$

**Trivial lower bound (fail)**

To get a trivial lower bound for $k$ :

- we consider the known lower bound ${(\frac{n}{p})}^{^p} \leq {{n}\choose{p}}$ for the binomial coefficient which leads also to ${(\frac{n}{p})}^{^p} \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{p} {{n}\choose{i}}$ for the binomial partial sum
- we rewrite the equation by using this bound in order to get what we want :

$$2^m \leq {(\frac{n}{k+1})}^{^{k+1}} \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1} {{n}\choose{i}} $$

- which leads to :
  $$ m \leq (k+1)\log (n) - (k+1)\log (k+1) $$
- But I'm stuck here : I fail in grouping the $k$ together :-(

Comment: Maybe related: [Sum of 'the first k' binomial coefficients for fixed n](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n).

Answer (score 0):

**Handy hint.**
You can use special functions for the lower bound. Indeed, the equation
\begin{equation}
y = a x - x \ln x
\end{equation}
with $x=k+1$, $y=m \ln 2$ and $a=\ln n$, rewrites as
\begin{equation}
-y\, \text{e}^{-a} = \left(\ln x - a\right) \text{e}^{\ln x - a} \, ,
\end{equation}
which is of the form $Y = X \text{e}^X$. The solutions of such equations are given by $X = W(Y)$, where $W$ denotes the Lambert $W$-function (see e.g. the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)). Thus, the equality case of the lower bound is
\begin{equation}
k+1 = n\exp\left(W\!\left(-\frac{m \ln 2}{n}\right)\right)\, .
\end{equation}